# PCRE Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, pcre

I have found an error in PHP's PCRE but before I post a bug report I want to test the same expression via the command line in Windows to see if it has the same error. If the error is in PCRE itself I need to post the report on the PCRE site, otherwise on the PHP site. Are there any tools to run a PCRE directly from the Windows command line using the library I already have installed?

Comment: no. pcre is just a library, it doesn't have a 'front-end'. That's PHP's job.

Comment: @MarcB What I'm asking is has anyone written a 'front-end' that uses the PCRE library that I can just download? I have found pcretest, but I'd need to compile it myself and I can't do that because I don't have a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Perl script and a Perl interpreter to test your regex. On Windows, I recommend installing Cygwin(and Perl can be selected in setup.exe for a Perl interpreter). Alternatively, if you want a somewhat slimmer installation, use StrawberryPerl: http://strawberryperl.com/

I wouldn't recommend using a purely command line test as the Windows command prompt is prone to escaping errors.

**Please note you'll need to use [http://metacpan.org/pod/re::engine::PCRE](http://metacpan.org/pod/re%3a%3aengine%3a%3aPCRE) to make your test legitimate**

Comment: Wouldn't I then be using Perl's regex library and not PCRE? I'm trying to see whether the bug is in PCRE or PHP.

Comment: ...also the Perl PCRE library you mention seems quite old

Comment: The library I linked was last updated in 2011. You'd be using PCRE as opposed to Perl's regex library if you used the above library.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I posted the bug on PHP anyway based on my best guess (is it a PHP or PCRE bug?) Some nice person ran the offending regex with pcretest and found that it behaves as expected (i.e. gives the proper error). So, the bug is definitely in PHP! The regex (in case you're wondering) is `/\k/`. It is invalid as it should be followed by a named back-reference (http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php), but PHP 5.4.4 allows it to compile and run.

I still can't run PCRE on the command line (pre-compiled Windows binaries anyone?)